# How to initialize after: Error: cannot call methods on autocomplete prior to initialization

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-ui, autocomplete

I previously had a an old autocomplete script running with an older jQuery on an input form. I wanted to add markItUp to my text entry form and the autocomplete version I was using was no longer working with the newer jQuery.

I saw that the latest autocomplete was available in jquery-ui.js, but after installing that I started getting the following warning:

> Error: cannot call methods on autocomplete prior to initialization;
>   attempted to call method '/include/suggest.php'

I looked up initialization and added this after `$(document).ready(function()`:

```
$(this.target).find('input').autocomplete();
```

Same error message. So I tried making it more specific to the input field that's being autocompleted:

```
$(this.target).find("input[id^='last_']").autocomplete();
```

I'm sort of flying blind here. The autocomplete stuff for this page was done by someone I no longer have access to and I've never really written jQuery stuff myself. I'm trying to understand this but right now, I'm stumped.

Here's a skeleton of the page:

```
<script src="/jquery/1.9.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="/inc/auto/main.css" type="text/css" />
<link rel="stylesheet" href="ui/1.11.4/themes/smoothness/jquery-ui.css">
<script src="/js/markitup/jquery.markitup.js"></script>
<script src="/js/markitup/sets/default/set.js"></script>

    [markitup styles]

<script>
  function html_entity_decode(str)
  {
    var ta=document.createElement("textarea");
    ta.innerHTML=str.replace(/</g,"&lt;").replace(/>/g,"&gt;");
    return ta.value;
  }
    $(document).ready(function() {
  $("#markItUp").markItUp(mySettings);

    $(this.target).find('input').autocomplete();
    $("input[id^='last_']").autocomplete('/include/suggest.php',{
            matchCase:true,
            formatItem: function(data, i, total)
            {
                var s=data[0].split(",")
                return s.join(" "); 
            }
    });

    $("input[id^='last_']").result(function(event, data, formatted){

        var ids=this.id.split('_')
        var id=ids[1]; // from last_xx got xxx

        var s=html_entity_decode(data[0]).split(",");

        $(this).next().focus();
        $(this).next().select();

        //have only last value -- TAB pressed
        if(s.length==1)return;

        $('#first_'+id).val(s[0]);
        $('#middle_'+id).val(s[1]);
        $('#last_'+id).val(s[2]);
    });

       });
</script>
</head>
<body>
<h1>News Inserter</h1>
<form action="/forms/cronkite.shtml"  accept-charset="UTF-8" method="POST">

Reporter (Last, First Middle):<br />
<input type="text" id="last_1" name="lastreporters" size="15" maxlength="30" value="" />, <input type="text" id="first_1"     name="firstreporters" size="15" maxlength="30" value="" /><input type="text" id="middle_1" name="middlereporters" size="15" maxlength="30" value="" /><br />
Story:<br />
[markitup text area]
<input type="SUBMIT" value="Insert Data" /><input type="RESET" value="Reset" /><br />
</form>
```

Is the problem solely in my initialization call? One additional point: the autocomplete version I was using was Autocomplete - jQuery plugin 1.1pre Copyright 2007. Has the jQuery-ui version of autocomplete changed enough that I need to update my forms?

Answer (score -4, accepted):

After digging through tutorials, I see that jquery-ui has changed things quite a bit. Off to the tutorials!

Answer (score 1):

I Have Faced Same Problem Due to Older Version Of Jquery, Then I Have added "http://code.jquery.com/jquery-migrate-1.0.0.js" Js Now All Works Fine.